# What function separate table into multiple tables by category?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a continuation of ([Issues with cumsum in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992528/issues-with-cumsum-in-r)). So I use the following data to code to produce a rather nice data summary. The last item is my attempt to produce a desired final result shown at bottom. The difficulty is getting it to produce separate results. Any thoughts on how to do this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

employment <- c(1,45,125,130,165,260,2,46,127,132,167,265,50,61,110,121,170,305,55,66,112,123,172,310)
small <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,1,2,2,3,4)
area <-c(001,001,001,001,001,001,001,001,001,001,001,001,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003)
year<-c(2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020)
qtr <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)

smbtest <- data.frame(employment,small,area,year,qtr)


smbsummary2<-smbtest %>% 
  mutate(period = paste0(year,"q",qtr)) %>%
  select(area,period,employment,small) %>%
  group_by(area,period,small) %>%
  summarise(employment = sum(employment), worksites = n(), 
    .groups = 'drop_last') %>% 
  mutate(employment = cumsum(employment),
    worksites = cumsum(worksites))

smblonger2 <-smbsummary2 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = employment:worksites,
               names_to = "measure", values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(area,measure) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = period, values_from = value) %>% function???()
```

Final Result. How do I have it produce the two employment tables and then the two worksites table but in separate fashion.

```r
Area 001 Employment
smb    2020q1     2020q2  
1        46        111
2       301        342
3       466        512
4       726        817

Area 003 Employment
smb    2020q1     2020q2  
1        48        121
2       307        356
3       474        528
4       739        838
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_split` from `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

employment <- c(1,45,125,130,165,260,2,46,127,132,167,265,50,61,110,121,170,305,55,66,112,123,172,310)
small <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,1,2,2,3,4)
area <-c(001,001,001,001,001,001,001,001,001,001,001,001,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003)
year<-c(2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020)
qtr <-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)

smbtest <- data.frame(employment,small,area,year,qtr)

smbsummary2<-smbtest %>% 
  mutate(period = paste0(year,"q",qtr)) %>%
  select(area,period,employment,small) %>%
  group_by(area,period,small) %>%
  summarise(employment = sum(employment), worksites = n(), 
    .groups = 'drop_last') %>% 
  mutate(employment = cumsum(employment),
    worksites = cumsum(worksites))

smbsummary2 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = employment:worksites, names_to = "measure", values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(area,measure) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = period, values_from = value) %>%
  group_split()
```

Output

```r
#> <list_of<
#>   tbl_df<
#>     area   : double
#>     small  : double
#>     measure: character
#>     2020q1 : double
#>     2020q2 : double
#>   >
#> >[4]>
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>    area small measure    `2020q1` `2020q2`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     1 employment       46       48
#> 2     1     2 employment      301      307
#> 3     1     3 employment      466      474
#> 4     1     4 employment      726      739
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>    area small measure   `2020q1` `2020q2`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     1 worksites        2        2
#> 2     1     2 worksites        4        4
#> 3     1     3 worksites        5        5
#> 4     1     4 worksites        6        6
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>    area small measure    `2020q1` `2020q2`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     3     1 employment      111      121
#> 2     3     2 employment      342      356
#> 3     3     3 employment      512      528
#> 4     3     4 employment      817      838
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>    area small measure   `2020q1` `2020q2`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     3     1 worksites        2        2
#> 2     3     2 worksites        4        4
#> 3     3     3 worksites        5        5
#> 4     3     4 worksites        6        6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>